# xslt foreach and break

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I know that in xslt not have the break statement and don't know how to solve my problem.

Example

```
      <tag name="param" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="param" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="param" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="Token" />
      <tag name="return"/>
```

Parameter must be grouped with all token before next param. How I can do it?

Output must be something like this:

```
param
    Token
    Token
    Token
param
    Token
param
    Token
    Token
    Token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to achieve this would be a key to match the "non-param" elements, grouping them by the first most preceding param-element

```
<xsl:key 
  name="params" 
  match="tag[@name!='param']" 
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag[@name='param'][1])" />
```

Then, you would start by matching your "param" elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="tag[@name='param']" />
```

And for each one you match, you could then select the associated tags in group by using the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('params', generate-id())" />
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />
   <xsl:key name="params" match="tag[@name!='param']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag[@name='param'][1])" />

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tag[@name='param']" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tag[@name='param']">
      <xsl:text>param&#10;</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('params', generate-id())" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tag">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', @name, '&#10;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML (assuming a root lelement), the following is output

```
param
 - Token
 - Token
 - Token
param
 - Token
param
 - Token
 - Token
 - Token
 - return
```

If you don't want the "return" element you could add another template to match it and then ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 2.0 this would be easy, using `for-each-group`, but in XSLT 1.0 it's less straightforward.  One way to distinguish the groups is by counting the following-sibling `param` tags:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/tag[@name = 'param']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tag[@name = 'param']">
    <xsl:text>param&#x0a;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[@name = 'Token']
       [count(following-sibling::tag[@name='param'])
         = count(current()/following-sibling::tag[@name='param'])]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tag[@name = 'Token']">
    <xsl:text>&#x09;Token&#x0a;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we're selecting the `Token` tags that have the same number of following `param` tags as the `param` we started with, i.e. those that occur before the next param.  Note that this is rather inefficient, being O(N<sup>2</sup>) in the number of tags.  A more efficient approach would be to use a tail-recursive template, having each Token "look ahead" to see if it is the last Token before the next param:

```
<xsl:template match="tag[@name = 'param']">
  <xsl:text>param&#x0a;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[1][@name = 'Token']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag[@name = 'Token']">
  <xsl:text>&#x09;Token&#x0a;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[1][@name = 'Token']" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here the `param` template applies templates to the *first* following Token, and the Token template checks whether its first following sibling is another Token, and if so applies templates recursively.

Comment: +1 for the second solution, often referred to as "sibling recursion". It's worth mastering this technique even for XSLT 2.0 where it is rarely needed.